# Spark partitionBy much slower than without it

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I tested writing with:

```
 df.write.partitionBy("id", "name")
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .parquet(filePath)
```

However if I leave out the partitioning:

```
 df.write
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .parquet(filePath)
```

It executes 100x(!) faster.

Is it normal for the same amount of data to take 100x longer to write when partitioning?

There are 10 and 3000 unique `id` and `name` column values respectively. 
The `DataFrame` has 10 additional integer columns.

Comment: Does it cause a shuffle?

Comment: How much data is involved? It may be it all fits on one partition before you force it to be partitioned.

Comment: @Gillespie how can i find out?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul just 2 gb for this test.. I needed it partitioned as a simple search was taking ages, whereas a relational db would have returned instantly.  With what i have seen thus far I think parquet might be the wrong choice.

Comment: Have a look at the spark ui to see if/how much gets shuffled

Comment: @Gillespie thats what i was thinking.  Will have to find out how to do it on google dataproc.

Comment: Should also be in the logs

Comment: @Gillespie It appears that due to the large number of `name` column values the data is shuffling excessively.  When I partition by the `id` column alone, it works great.

Comment: Check if this link https://medium.com/a-muggles-pensieve/writing-into-dynamic-partitions-using-spark-2e2b818a007a is useful

Answer (score 1):

The first code snippet will write a parquet file per partition to file system (local or HDFS). This means that if you have 10 distinct ids and 3000 distinct names this code will create 30000 files. I suspect that overhead of creating files, writing parquet metadata, etc is quite large (in addition to shuffling).

Spark is not the best database engine, if your dataset fits in memory I suggest to use a relational database. It will be faster and easier to work with.

Comment: Do u mean parquet is not the best db storage?  I am setting up jdbc to postgres to test performance.  I dont think the data has to fit in memory.. Isnt that the point behind spark?

Comment: parquet file format is actually quite good, however if Spark is the right tool for the job depends heavily on your use-case. Spark is optimized for parallel processing of large amount of data. If you have a few or even 100 gigabytes of data a database like postgresql probably will be a better choice. Though without knowing your use case it is hard to give any recommendations.

Comment: Spark is being used by some to handle PBs of data.  I believe Spark is able   to process data from any supported source in parallel, including JDBC.  I have about 250GB to process that can be partitioned to files about 1GB in size to run in parallel.

Comment: How often does this data need to be processed? How often is it updated? If your data is in the database you will have to "load" it into Spark. The load process can be parallelized but you will still have to transfer 250GB of data via network. Will the whole process of transferring data and running analysis on multiple hosts be faster than a SQL query? What about hardware requirements?

Comment: BTW you don't have to partition data into separate files to process them in parallel in Spark. For parquet files Spark will create a task per HDFS block  and will schedule them according to available cores and data locality.

Comment: How is it parallelized for JDBC databases?  Spark won't load all the data into memory as long as one does not call `load()`, right?

Comment: Spark can execute multiple queries in parallel to load data. However if this is faster depends on your database, hardware, network, etc. See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases (partitionColumn). Spark DataFrame doesn't load all data in memory at once, instead it uses JDBC API to issue a SQL query to a database on every operation.

Comment: That makes sense and is inline with my experience so far.  I am going to try writing parquet data uncompressed and see what that does for  performance.