# Spark write to file with append to s3 - Cost issue

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, spark-streaming

So I have an Apache Spark stream that writes to S3 parquet files partition by day and hour every 20 minutes.
It seems that each batch before it writes, it executes "ls" and "head" on all the folders of this Table (/ root folder) name.

Since we have multiple days X 24 hours X different tables this incurs relatively high S3 costs overall.

Please note that our schema is being changed dynamically.

So my questions are:

1. Is it correct that the the writes recursively read all parquet head ?
2. Why the stream does not cache this information / Is it possible to cache it ?
3. Can you suggest the best practice ?

//Write code:

```
  withPartition.write()
                .format(format)
                .mode(SaveMode.Append)
                .partitionBy("day","hour")
                .save(path);
```

It seems that this issue is related to:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20049

[Spark partitionBy much slower than without it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32898218/spark-partitionby-much-slower-than-without-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that spark partition by is the cause of this problem:

[Spark partitionBy much slower than without it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32898218/spark-partitionby-much-slower-than-without-it)

So I implement it as follows and it fixed the problem, moreover it improved performence:

```
 withPartition = withPartition.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK());
    Dataset<DayAndHour> daysAndHours = withPartition.map(mapToDayHour(), Encoders.bean(DayAndHour.class)).distinct();

    DayAndHour[] collect = (DayAndHour[])daysAndHours.collect();
    Arrays.sort(collect);
    logger.info("found " + collect.length +" different days and hours: "
            + Arrays.stream(collect).map(DayAndHour::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","))  );
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(DayAndHour dayAndHour : collect){
        int day = dayAndHour.getDay();
        int hour = dayAndHour.getHour();
        logger.info("Start filter on " + dayAndHour);
        Dataset<Row> filtered = withPartition.filter(filterDayAndHour(day, hour))
                .drop("day", hour");

            String newPath = path + "/"
                    + "day" +"=" +day +"/"
                    + "hour" +"=" + hour;

            long specificPathCount = filtered.count();
            long timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
            logger.info("writing " + specificPathCount+  " event to " + newPath  );

            filtered.write()
                    .format(format)
                    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
                    .save(newPath);

            logger.info("Finish writing partition of " + dayAndHour+  " to "+ newPath+ ". Wrote [" + specificPathCount  +"] events  in " + TimeUtils.tookMinuteSecondsAndMillis(timeStart, System.currentTimeMillis()));
 }
    logger.info("Finish writing " + path+  ". Wrote [" + cnt  +"] events  in " + MinuteTimeUtils.tookMinuteSecondsAndMillis(time, System.currentTimeMillis()));
    withPartition.unpersist();

private static  MapFunction<Row, DayAndHour> mapToDayHour() {
    return new MapFunction<Row, DayAndHour>() {
        @Override
        public DayAndHour call(Row value) throws Exception {
            int day = value.getAs("day");
            int hour = value.getAs(hour");
            DayAndHour dayAndHour = new DayAndHour();
            dayAndHour.setDay(day);
            dayAndHour.setHour(hour);
            return dayAndHour;
        }
    };
}

private static  FilterFunction<Row> filterDayAndHour(int day, int hour) {
    return new FilterFunction<Row>() {
        @Override
        public boolean call(Row value) throws Exception {
            int cDay = value.getAs("day");
            int cHour = value.getAs(hour");

            return day == cDay && hour == cHour;
        }
    };
}
```

//And another POJO

```
public class DayAndHour implements Serializable , Comparable<DayAndHour>{

    private int day;
    private int hour;

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(int day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public int getHour() {
        return hour;
    }

    public void setHour(int hour) {
        this.hour = hour;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        DayAndHour that = (DayAndHour) o;

        if (day != that.day) return false;
        return hour == that.hour;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = day;
        result = 31 * result + hour;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" +
                "day=" + day +
                ", hour=" + hour +
                ')';
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(DayAndHour dayAndHour) {
        return Integer.compare((day * 100) + hour, (dayAndHour.day * 100) + dayAndHour.hour);
    }
}
```